# Angular route resolver does not work on Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

My resolve method:

```
resolve() : Observable<INews> {
 return this.newsService.getnonpaginatednews().pipe(
  map(resp => {
    return this.news = resp.result;
  })
 )
}
```

My News Service:

```
getnonpaginatednews(){
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'news/getnonpaginatednews');
}
```

My Routing Module:

```
{
  path : '',
  component: NewsComponent,
  resolve : {
    newsData : ApiResolverGuard
  }
}
```

My component method inside "onInit"

```
  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.getnonpaginatednews();
  }


  getnonpaginatednews(){
    let nonPaginatedNews = this.route.snapshot.data['newsData'];
    this.nonPaginatedNews = nonPaginatedNews.result;
  }
```

But the below code works:

```
resolve() : Observable<INews> {
  return this.newsService.getnonpaginatednews().pipe(take(1))
}
```

Just wanted to understand why it does not work on subscribe? Or pipe should always be used for resolving data?

Comment: make an example on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

In your first implementation, you used the map() operator to transform the response from an HTTP request and assigned it to a property. However, you did't return the transformed value as an Observable, so the resolve() method completed before the HTTP request finished.

The take(1) operator inside the pipe() method in your second implementation completes the Observable stream after the first emission and returns the value as an Observable. This is what the resolve() method expects.